# How do I call a function that has arguments from a for_each loop?

Tags: c++, foreach

I have a C++ program that stores objects in a vector, and then uses `std::for_each` to call a function on each object.  I don't understand how to write the `std::for_each` loop if the called function needs to take arguments.

Here is an example of code that I would like to work:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

class BaseClass
{
    public:
        virtual void Setup() = 0;
        virtual void DisplayText(int key, int x, int y) = 0;
};

class A: public BaseClass
{
    public:
        void Setup();
        void DisplayText(int key, int x, int y);
};

class B: public BaseClass
{
    public:
        void Setup();
        void DisplayText(int key, int x, int y);
};

void demo(A *a, B *b, std::vector<BaseClass*>& storageVector)
{
    storageVector.push_back(a);
    storageVector.push_back(b);

    std::for_each (storageVector.begin(), storageVector.end(),
        std::mem_fn(&BaseClass::Setup));

    std::for_each (storageVector.begin(), storageVector.end(),
        std::mem_fn(&BaseClass::DisplayText));
}
```

I get these errors from the compiler:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
error C2752: 'std::_Result_of<_Fty,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,
    _V5_t,<unnamed-symbol>,_Obj>' : more than one partial
    specialization matches the template argument list
```

If I try to pass arguments to the function, e.g.

```
for_each (storageVector.begin(), storageVector.end(),
    std::mem_fn(&BaseClass::DisplayText(0,0,0)));)
```

then I also get

```
error C2352: 'BaseClass::DisplayText' :
    illegal call of non-static member function
```

What am I missing?

Comment: errors often come with a line number. Do yours do that? which lines do they correspond to?

Comment: In the 2nd for_each loop, the DisplayText method should receive 3 parameters as announced in the declaration. maybe this is a problem.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It says that the error is in the file xrefwrap. Definitely a file I didn't touch. Wrote all of this in my source.cpp

Comment: Can you support c++11 syntax? What you're trying to do is much easier in c++11.

Comment: @average If it try to add in the values that gives me this error: error C2352: 'BaseClass::DisplayText' : illegal call of non-static member function. I added that information to the question. I don't know how to properly add in the arguments. This is what I tried, but it didn't work: for_each (storageVector.begin(), storageVector.end(), std::mem_fn(&BaseClass::DisplayText(0,0,0)));)

Comment: @b4hand I do not know. How do I know if I can support it or what type of C++ I am using?

Comment: @SyntaxIsEvil if your compiler recognizes new keywords (auto, nullptr, static_assert are easy to check) that's a good indicator, although not 100% sure since you may find partial support. The only safe way is if the compiler documentation explicitly states it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `DisplayText` requires three additional arguments which are not provided. You need to either:

Change `DisplayText` not to require any arguments

Or use a lambda that provides them:

```
for_each(storageVector.begin(), storageVector.end(),
   [](BaseClass* c){ c->DisplayText(key, x, y); });
```

Or use for-each loop that provides them:

```
for (auto c : storageVector)
    c->DisplayText(key, x, y);
```

Or bind the arguments to the functor:

```
for_each(storageVector.begin(), storageVector.end(),
    std::bind(std::mem_fn(&BaseClass::DisplayText), _1, key, x, y));
```

Comment: That auto for loop was exactly what I needed to get it to work. Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: I have added that possibility as well

Answer (score 3):

You can use lambda functions.

```
std::for_each (storageVector.begin(), storageVector.end(), [] (BaseClass* base) {base->Setup();});
std::for_each (storageVector.begin(), storageVector.end(), [] (BaseClass* base) {base->DisplayText(1, 2, 3);});
```

You can read more about lambda functions at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda.

Comment: I didn't know about lambda functions. Those are really neat. When I try to add that to my main though it gives me this error: IntelliSense: an enclosing-function local variable cannot be referenced in a lambda body unless it is in the capture list. Any idea why it would give me that?

Comment: lambda functions capture everything in its enclosing scope by using the syntax `[=](BaseClass* base) { }`. They can also capture specific names from the enclosing scope using `[a,b] (BaseClass* base) { }`.

Comment: Oh okay. I just needed to add the variables in the square brackets. That got that to work. Neat. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind some arguments to the function `DisplayText`, which takes 3 arguments `key`, `x`, and `y`. There are multiple ways to do this. For example, you could create your own functor object which does the binding or you could use a lambda.

The easiest approach is to bind constant values to the arguments, but you could also bind values that are computed based on some external information. Either way, you can't invoke `DisplayText` without providing all of its arguments.

In your second example, you are trying to "take the address" of a function with arguments. You can't do that directly in C++. Some other languages directly allow you to bind some number of arguments that are less than the actual number of declared arguments of the function, and this concept is known as currying. In languages, that don't support this, the typical approach is to use a closure to store the state of the additional arguments and allow the closure to be called later. This functionality is what C++11's lambda supports.

`for_each` expects a function that takes exactly one argument, but you are giving it something different, and that is what your error says. `std::mem_fn` takes a member function and turns it into a non-member callable object that takes an additional argument. That means you are now giving `for_each` something that expects 4 arguments instead of 1 argument. The first argument is the object to be called, and the 3 other arguments are the original arguments that `DisplayText` expects.

I'm going to show you the functor object approach because this will work even in older versions of C++, and it is in fact the way in which `std::function` and lambda objects work underneath the covers. C++11 has new syntax for doing this in a much terser fashion, but understanding how it works is useful to understanding the new syntax.

```
class F {
public:
    F(int key, int x, int y) : key(key), x(x), y(y) {}

    void operator()(BaseClass *d) const {
        d->DisplayText(key, x, y);
    }

private:
    int key;
    int x;
    int y;
};

for_each(storageVector.begin(), storageVector.end(), F(1, 2, 3));
```

If you do it this way, you'll find yourself writing lots of these one off throw away classes that all they do is store some given number of arguments with a specific type signature. Realizing this, you could generalize this class by templatizing the types of the arguments. Taking it one step further you could generalize it even more by taking a variable number of template parameters and thus supporting a variable number of arguments. This is exactly how the `std::function` type works.

Answer (score 0):

From cppreference.com, the signature of your function should be `void fun(const Type &a)`.  I believe the issue may be that your signatures either accept no arguments (in the case of `Setup`) or multiple arguments (in the case of `DisplayText`), which is not what the `for_each` is expecting.

You may need:

```
void my_func(const BaseClass &r_arg) {};
```